# whats the error? Expected !untrusted = true, and got false

Tags: javascript

Why !untrusted is false?. Thanks

```
var trusted="true"
var untrusted="false"

console.log(trusted,!trusted)             //true,false
console.log(untrusted,!untrusted)         //false,false
```

Comment: A non-empty string is always truly. So when you convert a truly value with this operator ! then it becomes falsely.

Comment: *`JSON.parse`*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you are seeing the ouput is because non-empty string is always true. You are using a string value, it should be a boolean,

```
var trusted=true;
var untrusted=false;
```

**DEMO**

```js
var trusted=true;
var untrusted=false;
console.log(trusted,!trusted);      
console.log(untrusted,!untrusted);
```

Comment: Excellent answer, Sajeetharan, but then i've a problem: values 'true' and 'false' comes from html tag, as:

<g id="Elemento1" trusted="true">

¿How i get trusted attribute as a boolean?

Comment: you can cast it to bool , var untrusted= Boolean("false");